# Не понимаю почему кидает ошибку TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, type-error

```
    chess=list(input("Введите номер клетки:  "))
    num=int(chess[-1])
    letter=str(chess[0])
    for num in chess:
        if letter=="a" :
            if num % 2 == 0:
                print("Клетка белая")
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Nikita Kondratev\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module> if num % 2 == 0: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Формат ввода строки какой? Что вообще должно вводиться? На какой строке вылетает ошибка?

Comment: ошибка на 6 строке

Comment: что-то не то вы поместили сюда, подозреваю. И поместите весь текст ошибки. (Код рабочий, просто бессмысленный).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nikita Kondratev\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    if num % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: какие входные данные - что на "Введите номер клетки:  " ввели для такой ошибки?

Comment: я вписал номер клетки и букву (a4)

Comment: А просите НОМЕР клетки. Вот НОМЕР и вводите!

Comment: даже так вылетает ошибка,

Comment: У вас в переменной num строка 'a', а вы ее напополам делите. Как-то нелогично!

Comment: Неправда. При вводе номера, например 11, 12 и пр.  или даже 1, 2 3 и пр. никакой ошибки не вылетает.

Comment: зачем вам `for num in chess:` - в чем идея? И что вы хотите иметь для остальных семи горизонталей?

Comment: Зачем вообще в список оборачивать строку?

Comment: где происходит оборот списка в строку?

Comment: `list(input())`, вот зачем тут `list()`?

Comment: чтобы достать из строки букву и цифру,или это можно сделать по другому?

Comment: советую поместить новый исправленный вопрос типа "как мне лучше переделать код?" с меткой "инспекция-кода", приведу вам код с комментариями, как правильнее сделать.

Comment: Спасибо, но я понял уже в чем ошибка была. Надо было просто удалить for num in chess:

Comment: ok. + там еще мелкие огрехи, да непонятно, как вы с остальными  семью строками собираетсь поступать